# Gitweb 404 error Mac OS X

Tags: git, gitweb

I am trying to view a local git repository with instaweb.

At first, I tried the following command in a cloned repository :

```
git instaweb --httpd=webrick
```

to receive the following error :

```
Not Found
`/' not found.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08) at 127.0.0.1:1234
```

I installed lighttpd (I am on a Mac OS X Mavericks machine) and tried

```
git instaweb
```

to receive a 404 error.

I then installed created an entirely new git repository via

```
git init
```

and tried both of the above again, to no avail.

My .gitconfig file looks like this :

```
[web]
    browser = ff
[browser "ff"]
    cmd = open -a Firefox.app
[core]
    editor = emacs
```

The .git/gitweb/lighttpd/error.log file looks like this :

```
2015-09-10 00:35:52: (log.c.164) server started
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: probably not the solution you're looking for but if you're on mac os I suggest you give [GitUp](http://gitup.co) a try

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same symptoms using git 2.3.8, which came with my default installation (`git version 2.3.8 (Apple Git-58)`).

I installed git 2.6.0 via brew (`brew install git`) and it worked after that (`git version 2.6.0`).

Comment: Awesome ! Didn't even think to do this (obviously). Thank you. I would +1 your answer if I had the reputation to...